# Angular 7: Insert value into the array using ngModel

Tags: angular

I know similar type of questions have been asked already but I tried them, to be honest I didn't get them I am very new to `angular 7` and most of the time I choose very simple solution without any complexity.

So I have an array of type `Students`, I created a variable student of type Students and now I am trying to insert these value into variable student. let me share code I will make my question more understandable.

**students.model.ts**

```
export class Students {
    public rollno: number
    public name: string;
    public year: number;
    public branch: string;
    public college: string;
    public password: string;

    constructor(rollno: number, name: string, branch: string, college: string, year: number, password: string) {
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.name = name;
        this.branch = branch;
        this.college = college;
        this.year = year;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**studentLogin.componen.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
import { Students } from 'src/app/shared/student.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-login',
  templateUrl: './student-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-login.component.css']
})
export class StudentLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  students: Students[] = []

  constructor(private studentServ: StudentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onStudentLogin() {
    console.log(this.students)
  }

}
```

**studentlogin.component.html**

```
<div class="my-flex">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-body text-center">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7">
                <div class="card bg-secondary border-0 mb-0">
                  <div class="card-body px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                    <div class="text-center text-muted mb-4">
                        <form>
                          <label>Student Login</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                              name="rollno" [(ngModel)]="students.rollno" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Roll no">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="password" class="form-control" 
                              name="password" [(ngModel)]="students.password" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                            </div> 
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onStudentLogin()">Submit</button>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 m-auto"><a routerLink="/studentRegister">Register ?</a></div>
                          </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>    
</div>
```

I am just trying to console the value of `students array` and I got this.

```
length: 0
​
password: "sdasdsa"
​
rollno: "1001"
```

It prints the value but length is 0.

Please help me out here, How can I insert the value into array.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the data from your student service inside `ngOnInit` and assign it to the `students` property.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.studentServ.getAll()
        .subscribe(students => this.students = students)
}
```

Comment: @TuhinKarmakr Thanx for replying but how do I get data that I enter into my form.

Comment: You need to write a method like `getAll()` in your `StudentService`. You can use a hardcoded array or fetch the data from some backend.